# State incrementing by more than expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

tearing my hair out here so would absolutely love some help.

I'm using ReactJS to make a language learning app, and have a parent component with to host a series of questions. The questions themselves are all contained in a child component called TestComponents, and when users get the a question right it should increment a state counter called `index` by one, then render the questions with this: `{questions[index]}`

But two of the five question components I've made are incrementing the count by two instead of one.

Each of the question components has this prop passed to it:
`handleCorrect={() => handleCorrect()}`

Which should call this function:

```
  const handleCorrect = () => {
    setCorrect(true);
    setIndex(prevIndex => prevIndex + 1);

    setTimeout(() => {
      setCorrect(false);
    }, 2000);
  };
```

So I can't see anywhere in there which should be causing that function to be called twice. And if I put a `console.log` in it, that only appears once in my console - not twice, so it seems like this is incrementing by two instead of by one, rather than just calling the function twice.

As I say, three of the question components work fine, but the two that are breaking it are the below - apologies, because they're both quite big, but I've scoured them to try and work out what is breaking it and just cannot spot it, so I'm worried that if I only put what seem to me like the relevant parts of them, I'm worried I'll miss the part that's actually breaking it!

I have, though, put a comment saying where I am intending for it to call that function in to highlight them.

The first is this:

```
export const Leniter = ({
  sentence,
  correctSentence,
  handleCorrect,
  handleSubmit,
  header,
  topic,
}) => {
  const [sentenceSplit, setSentenceSplit] = useState(sentence.split(" "));

  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const handleSubmitCheck = () => {
    setSubmitted(true);
  };

  const handleClick = (word, index) => {
    setSubmitted(false);

    if (word.slice(1, 2) == "h") {
      let sentence2 = [...sentenceSplit];
      let word2 = word.slice(0, 1) + word.slice(2);
      sentence2[index] = word2;
      setSentenceSplit(sentence2);
    } else {
      let sentence2 = [...sentenceSplit];
      let word2 = word.slice(0, 1) + "h" + word.slice(1);
      sentence2[index] = word2;
      setSentenceSplit(sentence2);
    }
  };


//********Call the handleCorrect prop here*********
  //handleCorrect / incorrect on submit
  if ((!handleSubmit || (handleSubmit && submitted)) &&
    sentenceSplit.join(" ") == correctSentence) 
    {
      handleCorrect(topic);
      setSubmitted(false)
      setSentenceSplit(sentence.split(" "))
    }

  handleSubmit &&
    submitted &&
    sentenceSplit.join(" ") !== correctSentence &&
    console.log("incorrect");

  return (
    <div className="testComponent">
      {header && header == "default" ? (
        <h3>
          Add or remove the <i>h</i> to make the correct form of the words:
        </h3>
      ) : (
        header && <h3>{header}</h3>
      )}

      <Paper
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          flexWrap: "wrap",
          listStyle: "none",
          minHeight: "20px",
          backgroundColor:
            (!handleSubmit || (handleSubmit && submitted)) &&
            sentenceSplit.join(" ") == correctSentence
              ? "lightgreen"
              : handleSubmit &&
                submitted &&
                sentenceSplit.join(" ") !== correctSentence
              ? "red"
              : "aliceblue",
          p: 0.5,
          m: 0,
          borderRadius: "5px 5px 5px 5px",
          border: "1px solid grey",
        }}
      >
        {sentenceSplit.map((word, index) => {
          return (
            <Chip
              onClick={(word) => handleClick(word.target.textContent, index)}
              label={word}
              sx={{ marginLeft: "5px" }}
            />
          );
        })}
      </Paper>

      {handleSubmit && (
        <SubmitBtn variant="contained" onClick={() => handleSubmitCheck()}>
          Submit
        </SubmitBtn>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

And the second is this:

```
export const AccentSelector = ({
  sentence,
  handleCorrect,
  handleSubmit,
  header,
  topic,
}) => {
  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);

  let accents = "aàeèiìoòuùAÀEÈIÌOÒUÙ";

  const [selectValue, setSelectValue] = useState([{}]);

  const handleChange = (event, index) => {
    setSubmitted(false);
    setCorrect([]);
    setSelectValue([
      ...selectValue,
      { index: index, value: event.target.value },
    ]);
  };

  //handleCorrect/incorrect
  const [correct, setCorrect] = useState([]);

  const handleSubmitCheck = () => {
    setCorrect([]);
    setSubmitted(true);
  };

  console.log(submitted, correct)

//********Call the handleCorrect prop here*********
  if (
    submitted &&
    correct.length > 0 &&
    correct.includes("true") &&
    !correct.includes("false")
  ) {
    handleCorrect();
    setSelectValue([{}]);
    setCorrect([])
  }

  return (
    <div className="testComponent">
      {header && header == "default" ? (
        <h3>Select the correct versions of the vowels:</h3>
      ) : (
        header && <h3>{header}</h3>
      )}
      <h3>
        {sentence.split("").map((letter, index) => {
          if (accents.split("").includes(letter)) {
            let val =
              selectValue.filter((arrayVal) => arrayVal.index == index).length >
              0
                ? selectValue.filter((arrayVal) => arrayVal.index == index)[
                    selectValue.filter((arrayVal) => arrayVal.index == index)
                      .length - 1
                  ].value
                : "?";

            let bgColor =
              (!handleSubmit || (handleSubmit && submitted)) &&
              selectValue.filter((arrayVal) => arrayVal.index == index).length >
                0 &&
              selectValue.filter((arrayVal) => arrayVal.index == index)[
                selectValue.filter((arrayVal) => arrayVal.index == index)
                  .length - 1
              ].value == letter
                ? "lightgreen"
                : (!handleSubmit || (handleSubmit && submitted)) &&
                  selectValue.filter((arrayVal) => arrayVal.index == index)
                    .length > 0 &&
                  selectValue.filter((arrayVal) => arrayVal.index == index)[
                    selectValue.filter((arrayVal) => arrayVal.index == index)
                      .length - 1
                  ].value != "?"
                ? "red"
                : "aliceblue";

            //push to Correct array
            if (bgColor == "lightgreen" && !correct.includes("true")) {
              setCorrect([...correct, "true"]);
            }

            if (
              (bgColor == "red" || bgColor == "aliceblue") &&
              !correct.includes("false")
            ) {
              setCorrect([...correct, "false"]);
            }

            switch (letter) {
              case "a":
              case "à":
                return (
                  <>
                    <Select
                      onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, index)}
                      value={val}
                      autoWidth
                      label={index}
                      size="small"
                      style={{
                        backgroundColor: bgColor,
                      }}
                    >
                      <MenuItem value="?">?</MenuItem>
                      <MenuItem value="a">a</MenuItem>
                      <MenuItem value="à">à</MenuItem>={" "}
                    </Select>
                  </>
                );
                break;
              case "è":
              case "e":
                return (
                  <>
                    <Select
                      onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, index)}
                      value={val}
                      autoWidth
                      label={index}
                      size="small"
                      style={{
                        backgroundColor: bgColor,
                      }}
                    >
                      <MenuItem value="?">?</MenuItem>
                      <MenuItem value="e">e</MenuItem>
                      <MenuItem value="è">è</MenuItem>={" "}
                    </Select>
                  </>
                );
                break;
              default:
                return <>broken</>;
            }
          } else {
            return <>{letter}</>;
          }
        })}
      </h3>
      {handleSubmit && (
        <SubmitBtn variant="contained" onClick={() => handleSubmitCheck()}>
          Submit
        </SubmitBtn>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: Hi! Please **reduce** the code in your question to a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Try to pass handleCorrect as follows handleCorrect={handleCorrect}

Comment: It's still doing the same thing @GeorgeMakroglou unfortunately!

Comment: You should not call this `if ((!handleSubmit || (handleSubmit && submitted)) &&
    sentenceSplit.join(" ") == correctSentence) 
    {
      handleCorrect(topic);
      setSubmitted(false)
      setSentenceSplit(sentence.split(" "))
    }` in function body directly. You can do it in `useEffect`.

Comment: You are a genius and a hero @LikiCrus, that has fixed it - thank you so, so much

Comment: @GordonMaloney glad to hear that. Then let me add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call any logic to update `state` value in the component body.

e.g. You changed state twice by `setSubmitted` and `setSentenceSplit`.
So `handleCorrect` may be called twice because of state changes above.

```
    if ((!handleSubmit || (handleSubmit && submitted)) &&
    sentenceSplit.join(" ") == correctSentence) 
    {
      handleCorrect(topic);
      setSubmitted(false)
      setSentenceSplit(sentence.split(" "))
    }
```

You can do it in `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
if ((!handleSubmit || (handleSubmit && submitted)) &&
    sentenceSplit.join(" ") == correctSentence) 
    {
      handleCorrect(topic);
      setSubmitted(false)
      setSentenceSplit(sentence.split(" "))
    }

}, [submitted, handleCorrect, sentenceSplit, handleSubmit])
```